# merge two SQL Tables with similar column names

Tags: mysql, sql-server

i have two database tables:

> **resultspassed** with:
>
> id, name, device, passed

and

> **resultsfailed** with:
>
> id, name, device, failed, aborted, notrun

can I somehow merge these 2 tables with a select, so I'll get the following 'view':

> id, name, device, passed, failed, aborted, notrun

using '0' as default values for the missing information.

Unfortunately i cannot change this crappy database layout. I've seen a lot of suggestions using the "union" statement, but this doesn't fit to me, as i'm getting a "different number of columns" error.

thank you!

Comment: Please only tag the product you are using.  SQL Server and MySQL often require very different approaches to the same problem.

Comment: thank you, in fact we are evaluating both products for our project to be able to compare them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, name, device, passed, 0 as failed, 0 as aborted, 0 as notrun
from t1
union all
select id, name, device, 0, failed, aborted, notrun
from t2
```